# What does the phrase "cracking" imply

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

**Miguel you're cracking. I get it, but drinking away your problems won't help either.**

Does "cracking" convey, losing one's composure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Cracking*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cracking) is an adjective that means *great* ("a *cracking* good book"), but that doesn't make sense here, given the second sentence.

More likely it's simply the present participle of [*crack*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crack):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> 2 : to break, split, or snap apart
> // The statue *cracked* when she dropped it.

Figuratively, the passage would mean something like this:

> Miguel you're (hurting / struggling / having difficulty coping). I get it, but drinking away your problems won't help either.

Using the word in this way would normally imply that the person has suffered some kind of loss, trauma, or other stress that is making them turn to drinking in order to escape.